# Gradle project refresh failed: No signature of method PreDexCache.clear() applicable

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting a strange error during gradle sync of imported project. I do not understand how to solve.

```
Gradle project refresh failed
Error:No signature of method: com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.clear() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File, com.android.build.gradle.internal.LoggerWrapper) values: [E:\GardleWorkSpace\MAIN_APP\build\intermediates\dex-cache\cache.xml, ...]
Possible solutions: clear(java.io.File, com.android.utils.ILogger), load(java.io.File), grep(), collect(), every(), sleep(long, groovy.lang.Closure)
```

I have tried deleting and importing multiple times.
Also **E:\GardleWorkSpace\MAIN_APP\build** this folder does not exists in my machine.

Please help. I have tried searching a lot but no one with the same problem found. Error is suggesting some solution I do not understand how and where to apply.

build.gradle

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "Project");

android {

    dependencies {
        // Support Library Features (https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html)
        compile group:'com.android.support', name:'support-v4', version: '22.0.0'
        compile group:'com.android.support', name:'palette-v7', version: '21.0.0'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 221505001
        versionName "1.0"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) && Os.isArch("x86")) {
            javaMaxHeapSize "1g"
        } else {
            javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        quiet true  // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
        abortOnError false  // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
        ignoreWarnings true  // if true, only report errors
        checkAllWarnings true  // if true, check all issues, including those that are off by default
        warningsAsErrors true  // if true, treat all warnings as errors
        disable 'TypographyFractions', 'TypographyQuotes'  // turn off checking the given issue id's
        //enable 'RtlHardcoded','RtlCompat', 'RtlEnabled'  // turn on the given issue id's
        check 'NewApi', 'InlinedApi'  // check *only* the given issue id's
        noLines true  // if true, don't include source code lines in the error output
        showAll true  // if true, show all locations for an error, do not truncate lists, etc.
        textReport true  // if true, generate a text report of issues (false by default)
        textOutput 'stdout'  // location to write the output; can be a file or 'stdout'
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of gradle do you use?

Comment: please post your build.gradle files

Answer (score 2):

Try to call `./gradlew build`. If it will not help, please get me your build script

**EDITED**

If you get exception `Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']`,
then you need to update your gradle version. Do it in your root build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
    }
}
```

Replace version string `1.0.+` with the latest version, for exmple `1.2.3`.

**Remember**, that you should have latest gradle on your machine

Comment: after running this I am getting following error in line apply plugin: 'com.android.library' ::


A problem occurred evaluating project ':lib_project:recognition'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
   > Could not find implementation class 'com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin' for plugin 'c
om.android.library' specified in jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com
.android.tools.build/gradle/1.0.1/cd1ae9a4b885e8f07572d0f894f149533c082cc8/gradle-1.0.1.jar!/ME
TA-INF/gradle-plugins/com.android.library.properties.

Comment: @singularity, Please, checkout my edited answer, and keep in mind, that latest gradle version is 2.3, and if it doesn't installed on your machine, you need to install it